# How to install VLC 2.0.8

Tags: vlc, subtitles

With new version of VLC you cannot automatically download the subtitles.
The only solution is to install vlc-2.0.8:
I get the source file from [here](https://download.videolan.org/vlc/2.0.8/vlc-2.0.8.tar.xz).
The I run

```
tar xf vlc-2.0.8.tar.xz
```

after running

```
cd vlc-2.0.8
./configure
```

the result is

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU Objective C compiler... no
checking whether gcc accepts -g... no
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for egrep... (cached) /bin/grep -E
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc -std=gnu99... gcc3
checking for desktop-file-validate... desktop-file-validate
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for 3rd party libraries path... not found
checking for an Android system... no
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... (cached) pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... no
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for windres... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... yes
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... libc
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... 
         extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for buggy GNU/libc versions... not present
checking for shared objects suffix... .so
checking whether nanosleep is declared... yes
checking for daemon... yes
checking for fcntl... yes
checking for fstatvfs... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking for getenv... yes
checking for getpwuid_r... yes
checking for if_nameindex... yes
checking for if_nametoindex... yes
checking for isatty... yes
checking for lstat... yes
checking for memalign... yes
checking for mmap... yes
checking for openat... yes
checking for pread... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... yes
checking for posix_madvise... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for stricmp... no
checking for strnicmp... no
checking for strptime... yes
checking for uselocale... yes
checking for atof... yes
checking for atoll... yes
checking for dirfd... yes
checking for fdopendir... yes
checking for flockfile... yes
checking for fsync... yes
checking for getdelim... yes
checking for getpid... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for lldiv... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for nrand48... yes
checking for rewind... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strcasestr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strndup... yes
checking for strnlen... yes
checking for strsep... yes
checking for strtof... yes
checking for strtok_r... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for swab... yes
checking for tdestroy... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for working strcoll... yes
checking for accept4... yes
checking for pipe2... yes
checking for eventfd... yes
checking for vmsplice... yes
checking for sched_getaffinity... yes
checking for library containing poll... none required
checking for struct pollfd... yes
checking for library containing connect... none required
checking for socklen_t in sys/socket.h... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for library containing getaddrinfo... none required
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking for cos in -lm... yes
checking for lrintf in -lm... yes
checking for library containing dlopen... -ldl
checking for main in -lpthread... yes
checking for clock_nanosleep in -lrt... yes
checking for strncasecmp in strings.h... yes
checking search.h usability... yes
checking search.h presence... yes
checking for search.h... yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking xlocale.h usability... yes
checking xlocale.h presence... yes
checking for xlocale.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking netinet/udplite.h usability... no
checking netinet/udplite.h presence... no
checking for netinet/udplite.h... no
checking sys/eventfd.h usability... yes
checking sys/eventfd.h presence... yes
checking for sys/eventfd.h... yes
checking for net/if.h... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking machine/param.h usability... no
checking machine/param.h presence... no
checking for machine/param.h... no
checking sys/shm.h usability... yes
checking sys/shm.h presence... yes
checking for sys/shm.h... yes
checking linux/version.h usability... yes
checking linux/version.h presence... yes
checking for linux/version.h... yes
checking linux/dccp.h usability... yes
checking linux/dccp.h presence... yes
checking for linux/dccp.h... yes
checking scsi/scsi.h usability... yes
checking scsi/scsi.h presence... yes
checking for scsi/scsi.h... yes
checking linux/magic.h usability... yes
checking linux/magic.h presence... yes
checking for linux/magic.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking mntent.h usability... yes
checking mntent.h presence... yes
checking for mntent.h... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking zlib.h usability... no
checking zlib.h presence... no
checking for zlib.h... no
checking for DBUS... no
configure: error: No package 'dbus-1' found.
```

seems like there is a problem because now `make` doesnt work

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Update1 : After ignoring lots of errors with this long command `vlc-2.0.8$ ./configure --disable-lua --disable-mad --disable-avcodec --disable-swscale --disable-postproc  --disable-a52` I still receive this error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (xcb >= 1.6) were not met:

No package 'xcb' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XCB_CFLAGS
and XCB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Update2: Also installed these packages

```
sudo apt-get install libjack-jackd2-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep vlc
```

I still receive this error :

```
configure: error: Could not find lua. Lua is needed for some interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts. Use --disable-lua to ignore this error.
```

Update3: according to [sneetsher](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/1239/sneetsher) answer.

After running

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev
./configure --disable-lua
./compile
```

Compiler leaves lots of warnings. I just copy some parts here because of limitation with num of characters in each post

```
MAKE     : compat
 COMPILE : libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -I../include -I../include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT strlcpy.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/strlcpy.Tpo -c -o strlcpy.lo
MAKE     : doc
MAKE     : po
MAKE     : share
desktop-file-validate tmp-vlc.desktop
           sed -e 's,\@vlcdatadir\@,/usr/local/share/vlc,g' < "osdmenu/default.cfg.in" > osdmenu/default.cfg
MAKE     : src
if ! git \
            --git-dir="../.git/" describe \
            --tags --long --match '?.*.*' --always; then \
    fi > revision.tmp
fatal: Not a git repository: '../.git/'
if diff revision.tmp ./revision.txt >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
    else \
        mv -f -- revision.tmp ./revision.txt; \
    fi
MAKE     : .
 COMPILE : libvlc.lo
 COMPILE : libvlc.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libvlc.c: In function 'vlc_hold':
WARNING : libvlc.c:126: 15:  variable 'refs' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     uintptr_t refs;
               ^
 COMPILE : libvlc-module.lo
 COMPILE : libvlc-module.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
depbase=`echo missing.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT missing.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o missing.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
depbase=`echo version.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o version.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
depbase=`echo interface/dialog.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT interface/dialog.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o interface/dialog.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
depbase=`echo interface/interface.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT interface/interface.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o interface/interface.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
interface/interface.c: In function 'intf_DestroyAll':
WARNING : interface/interface.c:194: 9:  'vlc_object_kill' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:76) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         vlc_object_kill( p_intf );
         ^
depbase=`echo playlist/art.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT playlist/art.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o playlist/art.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
depbase=`echo playlist/thread.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT playlist/thread.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o playlist/thread.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
playlist/thread.c: In function 'playlist_Deactivate':
WARNING : playlist/thread.c:78: 5:  'vlc_object_kill' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:76) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     vlc_object_kill( p_playlist );
     ^
playlist/thread.c: In function 'LoopInput':
WARNING : playlist/thread.c:467: 5:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     if( ( p_sys->request.b_request || !vlc_object_alive( p_playlist ) ) && !p_input->b_die )
     ^
playlist/thread.c: In function 'LoopRequest':
WARNING : playlist/thread.c:525: 5:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     if( i_status == PLAYLIST_STOPPED || !vlc_object_alive( p_playlist ) )
     ^
WARNING : playlist/thread.c:543: 13:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             if( vlc_object_alive( p_playlist ) )
             ^
playlist/thread.c: In function 'Thread':
WARNING : playlist/thread.c:577: 5:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     while( vlc_object_alive( p_playlist ) || p_sys->p_input )
     ^
depbase=`echo playlist/control.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT playlist/control.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o playlist/control.lo
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
playlist/control.c: In function 'PlaylistVAControl':
WARNING : playlist/control.c:110: 5:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     if( !vlc_object_alive( p_playlist ) )
     ^
depbase=`echo playlist/engine.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
 COMPILE : lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wsign-compare -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-prototypes -Wvolatile-register-var -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pipe -fvisibility=hidden  -ffast-math -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=athlon64 -MT playlist/engine.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o playlist/engine.lo
.
.
.
In file included from ../../include/vlc_common.h:491:0,
                 from idummy.c:32:
idummy.c: In function 'DemuxHold':
WARNING : ../../include/vlc_threads.h:326: 25:  call to 'harmful_delay.constprop.1' declared with attribute warning: use proper event handling instead of short delay [enabled by default]
 #define msleep(d) msleep(check_delay(d))
                         ^
idummy.c:60:5: note: in expansion of macro 'msleep'
     msleep( 10000 ); /* FIXME!!! */
     ^
In function 'DemuxPause.part.0',
    inlined from 'DemuxPause':
WARNING : ../../include/vlc_threads.h:326: 25:  call to 'harmful_delay.constprop.1' declared with attribute warning: use proper event handling instead of short delay [enabled by default]
 #define msleep(d) msleep(check_delay(d))
                         ^
idummy.c:78:5: note: in expansion of macro 'msleep'
     msleep( 10000 ); /* FIXME!!! */
     ^
 COMPILE : libaccess_udp_plugin_la-udp.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_tcp_plugin_la-tcp.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_http_plugin_la-http.lo
http.c: In function 'OpenWithCookies':
WARNING : http.c:517: 13:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
             if( !vlc_object_alive (p_access) || Connect( p_access, 0 ) )
             ^
http.c: In function 'ReadData':
WARNING : http.c:779: 19:  comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         if( i_len > p_sys->i_chunk )
                   ^
http.c: In function 'Read':
WARNING : http.c:836: 19:  comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         if( i_len > i_next )
                   ^
WARNING : http.c:859: 9:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         if( p_sys->b_reconnect && vlc_object_alive( p_access ) )
         ^
http.c: In function 'Connect':
WARNING : http.c:1209: 17:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                 if( !vlc_object_alive (p_access) || p_sys->b_error )
                 ^
http.c: In function 'Request':
WARNING : http.c:1382: 9:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         if( !vlc_object_alive (p_access) || p_sys->b_error )
         ^
 COMPILE : libaccess_ftp_plugin_la-ftp.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_imem_plugin_la-imem.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_attachment_plugin_la-attachment.lo
 COMPILE : libsdp_plugin_la-sdp.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_rar_plugin_la-rar.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_rar_plugin_la-access.lo
 COMPILE : libstream_filter_rar_plugin_la-rar.lo
 COMPILE : libstream_filter_rar_plugin_la-stream.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_vdr_plugin_la-vdr.lo
 COMPILE : libaccess_alsa_plugin_la-alsa.lo
 COMPILE : libpulsesrc_plugin_la-vlcpulse.lo
In file included from ../audio_output/vlcpulse.c:24:0:
WARNING : ../../config.h:750: 0:  "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 COMPILE : libpulsesrc_plugin_la-pulse.lo
In file included from pulse.c:24:0:
WARNING : ../../config.h:750: 0:  "_REENTRANT" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _REENTRANT /**/
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 COMPILE : libaccess_shm_plugin_la-shm.lo
 COMPILE : libv4l2_plugin_la-video.lo
v4l2/video.c: In function 'InitVideo':
WARNING : v4l2/video.c:930: 13:  format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 5 has type 'v4l2_std_id' [-Wformat=]
             msg_Err( p_obj, "cannot set standard 0x%"PRIx64": %m", std );
             ^
WARNING : v4l2/video.c:933: 9:  format '%lx' expects argument of type 'long unsigned int', but argument 5 has type 'v4l2_std_id' [-Wformat=]
         msg_Dbg( p_obj, "standard set to 0x%"PRIx64":", std );
         ^
WARNING : v4l2/video.c:1434: 43:  'f_fps' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         es_fmt.video.i_frame_rate = lround(f_fps * 1000000.);
                                           ^
v4l2/video.c: In function 'GrabVideo':
WARNING : v4l2/video.c:556: 14:  'p_block' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     block_t *p_block;
              ^
 COMPILE : libv4l2_plugin_la-demux.lo
 COMPILE : libv4l2_plugin_la-access.lo
v4l2/access.c: In function 'AccessReadStream':
WARNING : v4l2/access.c:119: 9:  'vlc_object_alive' is deprecated (declared at ../../include/vlc_objects.h:81) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         if( !vlc_object_alive(access) )
         ^
 COMPILE : libv4l2_plugin_la-controls.lo
v4l2/controls.c: In function 'ControlSetCallback':
WARNING : v4l2/controls.c:172: 8:  'ret' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     if (ret)
        ^
 COMPILE : libxcb_screen_plugin_la-xcb.lo
 COMPILE : libdtv_plugin_la-access.lo
 COMPILE : libdtv_plugin_la-linux.lo
 COMPILE : libdtv_plugin_la-en50221.lo
dtv/en50221.c: In function 'en50221_SetCAPMT':
ERROR   : dtv/en50221.c:2234: 17:  implicit declaration of function 'dvbpsi_DeletePMT' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
                 dvbpsi_DeletePMT( p_pmt );
                 ^
dtv/en50221.c: At top level:
WARNING : dtv/en50221.c:2288: 12:  'en50221_OpenMMI' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int en50221_OpenMMI( cam_t * p_cam, unsigned i_slot )
            ^
WARNING : dtv/en50221.c:2328: 12:  'en50221_CloseMMI' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int en50221_CloseMMI( cam_t * p_cam, unsigned i_slot )
            ^
WARNING : dtv/en50221.c:2356: 15:  'en50221_GetMMIObject' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static mmi_t *en50221_GetMMIObject( cam_t * p_cam, unsigned i_slot )
               ^
WARNING : dtv/en50221.c:2381: 13:  'en50221_SendMMIObject' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void en50221_SendMMIObject( cam_t * p_cam, unsigned i_slot,
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Download XCB from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xcb-util

Comment: Still i have other errors. please see the update

Comment: Ok, i removed my answer till i get a working solution  and test it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Please notice the version I need to run is 2.0.8

Comment: Does `make` work now? If it doesn't can you add the output of `./configure` with all your previous arguments

Comment: @WOEITG I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get -y install liba52-0.7.4-dev libaa1-dev libasound2-dev libass-dev \
libavahi-client-dev libcaca-dev libcairo2-dev libcddb2-dev libcdio-dev libdca-dev \
libdirac-dev libdvbpsi-dev libdvdnav-dev libdvdread-dev libebml-dev libfaad-dev \
libflac-dev libfluidsynth-dev libfreetype6-dev libfribidi-dev libgcrypt11-dev \
libggi2-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglib2.0-0 libgnomevfs2-dev libgnutls-dev libhal-dev \
libid3tag0-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libkate-dev liblircclient-dev liblua5.1-0-dev \
libmad0-dev libmatroska-dev libmodplug-dev libmpcdec-dev libmpeg2-4-dev libmtp-dev \
libncursesw5-dev libnotify-dev libogg-dev liboggkate-dev libpango1.0-dev libpng12-dev \
libprojectm-dev libprojectm-qt-dev libproxy-dev libpulse-dev libqt4-dev libraw1394-dev \
librsvg2-dev libschroedinger-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libshout3-dev \
libsmbclient-dev libspeex-dev libsqlite3-dev libsvga1-dev libsysfs-dev libtag1-dev \
libtar-dev libgme-dev libtheora-dev libtool libtwolame-dev libudev-dev libupnp-dev \
libv4l-dev libva-dev libvcdinfo-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev \
libxcb-composite0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-randr0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
libxcb-xv0-dev libxcb-xvmc0-dev libxcb1-dev libxext-dev libxml2-dev libxpm-dev \
libxt-dev libxv-dev libzvbi-dev lua5.1 qt4-qtconfig libspeexdsp-dev libsamplerate0-dev
```

to install all the libraries

Comment: thanks for answer.now after running `./configure` I receive this error : `configure: error: Could not find lua. Lua is needed for some interfaces (rc, telnet, http) as well as many other custom scripts. Use --disable-lua to ignore this error.`

Comment: I run sudo `apt-get install lua5.1` but still get the same error

Comment: See the update inside my question

Comment: Whenever you are looking for compilation dependencies the packages are generally denoted with a lib<package>-dev. In you're case you probably want `liblua5.1-0-dev`.

Comment: Building from source is very hard to do and requires downloading packages☺

Comment: I dont have lementary os any more. may someone try and leave the feedback here

Comment: . Why did you remove it?

Comment: What about the question bounty ?

Comment: I will give you the bounty as you made a lots of effort for this :-) Elementary OS was full of errors and bugs for me. I received lots of errors and desktop environment acted very strange that I decided to install ubunto.

Comment: @WOEITG Thanks ☺ . My first bounty and I got some reputation

Comment: Woeitg, did you know that elementary OS freya is built from Ubuntu 14.04? I use it for quite a while now, and there were nearly no bugs at all. Instead of just ignoring them, you can post those "bugs" into the bugtracker, or you can even post them here and probably these weren't bugs but errors leading into configuration errors or system incompatibility, which can of course be fixed. But if that was your choice - nothing we can do about it.